# Boot issue with Debian Stretch 9.4 (amd64) on Dell R710

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc, scsi, debian-stretch

I'm hoping someone has seen this and can assist. This is more of an annoyance than a true issue.

I have a Dell R710 stacked with Debian 9.4 (amd64). The physical unit has the following characteristics:

- 2x Xeon X5550
- 32GB RAM
- Perc 6/i RAID Controller

  - 2x 146GB 15k SAS
  - 3x 146GB 10k SAS (combined as RAID disk)
  - 3x 300GB 10k SAS (combined as RAID disk)
- SATA DVD Drive

I am booting off of the first 15k SAS drive currently and not using the other drives at present.

The physical box has an internal USB & SD card port. I had previously booted another system on the internal and opted just to go with a physical disk at this time so there are no items in the USB or SD card port.

BIOS is set to boot to the "C:" drive (their naming ... not mine)

Once up the box runs like a champ with no issues. During boot however is another story.

Kernel Installed:

> Linux localhost 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

There is a 2 min+ gap during startup that I've seen the following errors associated with in dmesg:

```
[    2.513315] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 502
[    2.513378] DMAR: [DMA Read] Request device [03:00.0] fault addr fff0d000  [fault reason 06] PTE Read access is not set
[    2.518031] scsi 0:0:32:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0
[    2.617616] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    2.618173] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.35.0-ioctl (2016-06-23) initialised:  dm-devel@redhat.com
[    2.778729] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 602
[    2.778793] DMAR: [DMA Read] Request device [03:00.0] fault addr fff20000  [fault reason 06] PTE Read access is not set
[    2.783376] scsi 0:0:32:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0
[    2.972320] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    3.042491] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 702
[    3.042556] DMAR: [DMA Read] Request device [03:00.0] fault addr ffc83000  [fault reason 06] PTE Read access is not set
[    3.047175] scsi 0:0:32:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0
[    3.307839] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[    3.307915] DMAR: [DMA Read] Request device [03:00.0] fault addr ff3bb000  [fault reason 06] PTE Read access is not set
[    3.312489] scsi 0:0:32:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0
[    3.363044] random: crng init done
[    3.577114] scsi 0:0:32:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0
[    3.840869] scsi 0:0:32:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0
[    4.105521] scsi 0:0:32:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0
[    4.371579] scsi 0:0:32:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0
[    4.635322] scsi 0:0:32:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0
[    4.837103] ses 0:0:32:0: Attached Enclosure device
[  131.523048] PM: Starting manual resume from disk
```

The line

```
[    4.635322] scsi 0:0:32:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0
```

I believe is a known issue in the kernel (see [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/3/13/58)).

I had at one point done some lunacy and was running a stretch-backports kernel which was getting a different error (asked for 10 got 0).

Staying at the topic at hand - is there a way to tell the kernel to ignore device "0:0:32:0"?